# Kineticjs - Is there a way to highlight selected text?

Tags: kineticjs

I'd like to be able to select text and highlight selected text on a button click. I know I could use Jquery or Html5 'mark' but I'm drawing on a Pdf document so I can't really use it. Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you asked for any ideas...

**Here's a very rough outline of how to select & highlight Kinetic text.**

- Create a background layer to hold text highlights.
- (highlights are just filled rects drawn under selected text fragments).
- Create a foreground text layer to hold the actual text.
- Monitor mouse clicks to determine where a user clicks (where they desire selecting).
- Use context.measureText to determine which text is being selected by the user and draw a highlight rectangle on the background layer under the text to be highlighted.

Comment: Thanks. You certainly gave me some ideas